# Oracle - why do I need INITRANS if I have MAXTRANS?

Tags: oracle, performance, plsql

Probably is a dummy question, but I still don't understand why do I need the `INITRANS` parameter if I already have the `MAXTRANS` parameter. I have understand that, the default `INITRANS` for tables is 1 and index is 2, but also, we have the `MAXTRANS` that the default is 255 (I guess it depend of the block size). and, because we have 255 in MAXTRANS, the number of ITL can grow dynamically as needed, so, why do I need to care about `INITRANS`? can someone explain it?

I need to learn because I am having several event in a database: `enq: TX - allocate ITL entry`

Also, when I change the `INITRANS` of an existing table, do I need to move the table as well to affect all existing data block in that table? or just change the `INITRANS` is enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ITL cannot grow in a block that is already full.

INITRANS sets a guaranteed minimum to its size.

After changing INITRANS on a table, you need to move it so its blocks will be reorganized to reserve the required space for ITL.